# Color legend location in eps files, exported from paraview v5.4

Tags: paraview

I am getting this strange error with paraview 5.4. 
For example, if I load one of the example visualisations:
[image]

and if I export it as eps or pdf, then the color legend is place in the bottom left corner:
[image]

This does not happen for jpg or png files.
Anybody know how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. That's probably a bug, and you can report it on the [issue tracker o Paraview](https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/issues).

Comment: and should! (report it)